# Correlated Subqueries: resolving ambiguous names

Tags: subquery

Suppose I have 2 tables which share some column names. In this case the primary key is both is called `id`.

```
CREATE TABLE artists(
    id int primary key,
    name text,
--  …,

);
CREATE TABLE paintings(
    id int primary key,
    artistid references artists(id),
    title text,
--  …,
);
```

**Note:** *I know there are arguments against calling your primary key a generic name like `id`, but let’s suppose, for argument’s sake that it’s out of my control. In any case, it could have been any other column for the purpose of this question.*

Suppose I now have a carelessly written `SELECT` statement which seeks to extract data from the referenced table using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    id, title,
    (SELECT name FROM artists WHERE artistid=id) as artist
FROM paintings;
```

Clearly the inner `WHERE` clause could have been better written as `WHERE paintings.artistid=artists.id`. However I have got away with it and it works. It even works if I write the `WHERE` clause as `id=artistid`.

I know it’s not the best way to go about it, but I’m more surprised that it has understood my intention, which is not what we have come to expect from SQL.

The question is: **How does SQL interpret ambiguous columns in a Correlated Subquery?**

Comment: The rule is: the closest match wins. If there was an `artistid` **and** an `id` in the `artists` table those two would be compared. If the artists table had neither of those columns, the columns of the outer table would be compared

Answer (score 6):

It resolves the column names in scope order. Inside the sub query columns will be resolved against those from the `artists` table if there is such ambiguity.

[This can sometimes be quite useful](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44872/36900) though [it can also be quite dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4594765/73226).

I usually use table aliases and two part names to avoid any unexpected issues and make it clearer to the reader which table each column is from.

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.title,
       (SELECT a.name
        FROM   artists a
        WHERE  p.artistid = a.id) AS artist
FROM   paintings p;
```