# Subquery gives no error for a non-existing column with the same name as in the outer query

Tags: mysql, postgresql, subquery

I have two tables in a MySQL database - `t1` with a column `c1`, and `t2` with a column `c2`.

I run this query:

```
select * from t1 where c1 in (select c1 from t2);
```

The above query should give an error as `c1` is not present in t2. Instead, it returns all the rows from `t1`. Another version of the above query with `delete` which can be much more disastrous:

```
delete from t1 where c1 in (select c1 from t2);
```

The above query deletes all the rows from t1 when it is just supposed to give an error.

I have noticed this behavior occurs only when the column in the subquery has the same name as the outer one. Meaning,

```
select * from t1 where c1 in (select c3 from t2);
```

will throw an error as expected:

```
 ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'c3' in 'field list'
```

By the way, I have checked for the same issue on PostgreSQL 9.6.3 and the behavior is exactly the same. Any explanation for this strange behavior?

Comment: These visibility rules are mandated by the SQL standard

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I run this query:
>
> ```
> select * from t1 where c1 in (select c1 from t2);
> ```
>
> The above query should give an error as `c1` is not present in t2.
>   Instead, it returns all the rows from `t1`.

No, the query **should not** give an error. It's a common mistake (thinking that the `c1` in `(select c1 from t2)` refers to `t2`. It doesn't due to **scope resolution**, i.e. how column names are resolved (how it is found which table they are referring to). The query:

```
select * from t1 where c1 in (select c1 from t2);
```

Can resolve to three different options:

- when `t2` has a column named `c1`, it runs as:

  ```
  select * from t1 where c1 in (select t2.c1 from t2);
  ```
- when `t2` does not have a column named `c1`, but `t1` has, it runs as:
  (this is your case!)

  ```
  select * from t1 where c1 in (select t1.c1 from t2);
  ```
- and when neither `t2` nor `t1` have a column named `c1`, it will throw an error:

  ```
  select * from t1 where c1 in (select c1 from t2);
  ```

  -- Error is thrown ("Unknown column c1" or something like that)

> Another version of the
>   above query with `delete` which can be much more disastrous:
>
> ```
> delete from t1 where c1 in (select c1 from t2);
> ```
>
> The above query deletes all the rows from t1 when it is just supposed
>   to give an error.

For the same reasons, no. The query resolves to and runs as:

```
delete from t1 where c1 in (select t1.c1 from t2);
```

so it will delete all rows from `t1` as long as `t2` table is not empty.

---

How to avoid these problems?

Always prefix column references with their table names. By doing this, you will always have the result you want or get an error if the column doesn't appear in the table you are prefixing it with.

Your queries should be:

```
select t1.* from t1 where t1.c1 in (select t2.c1 from t2);

delete from t1 where t1.c1 in (select t2.c1 from t2);
```

Both of them will throw an error if there is no column `c1` in table `t2`.

Comment: While I understand the _how_ of this functioning (due to scope resolution), I can only come up with very contrived examples for this behavior to be appear useful in actual databases (as opposed to a very subtle-but-disastrous bug opportunity).  Am I missing some obvious use cases for columns in a subquery being selectable from outside the subquery scope?  [The behavior exists in other SQL platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612136/why-query-does-not-fail-with-nonexistent-column-in-subquery), so it seems to be an accepted convention.

Comment: @bsplosion The behaviour is according to SQL standard. All correlated subqueries is the most common use. Eg. writing `select * from t1 where c1 in (select c2 from t2);` as `select * from t1 where exists (select * from t2 where c1 = c2);` As to the unexpected behaviours in some occasions, it's usually due to human errors on writing wrong column name. That's why many recommend to always prefix columns with the respective table name. Others (not so common but I've seen it) prefer to have all column names across all tables in a database with different names, so prefixing is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  My comment was more speculation about whether there's a good reason to have that behavior to begin with.  Correlated subqueries make sense when outer values are used in filter conditions, though specifically _selecting_ values from the outer query via the subquery is more of a stretch - you could just select them in the outer if that's what you wanted, or leverage an exists clause instead (if trying to do a filtered `IN` clause).  Regardless, I'm sure people smarter than myself have a good reason to allow that behavior, I'm just having trouble seeing it.

Comment: Oh, in the select list of a subquery? Yeah, I don't think it is particularly useful there but there isn't good reason to make such an exclusion either.

Comment: @bsplosion for a very weird use case (or abuse if you like ;), see this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66741/why-cant-i-use-a-case-statement-to-see-if-a-column-exists-and-not-select-from-i?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Ha, and that links back to your [even more direct answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44872/180222) to the question about that select behavior, all the way from 2013!  So there _are_ ways to use it creatively, albeit carefully.  Still seems like the kind of thing that should come with a warning label, but that take is pretty nifty.

Comment: What does `select t1.c1 from t2` even mean? Isn't the last part `from t2` just discarded to make that work?

Answer (score 8):

It is actualy not an error.
You are really referencing the column from outer table.

Because of this "feature" you are able to write correlated subqueries and reference the fields from outer query in the inner query.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 where c1=c2)
```

Usually this is used in inner query WHERE clause but there is no reason why it wouldn't be used in the SELECT part. For example you might be wanting to concatenate or add field from outer query with field from inner to get the result.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE total IN (SELECT c1+c2 FROM t2 WHERE c2>c1)
```

The above is confusing so the best way to prevent errors as you describe is to prefix fields with table names to all the  fields.

```
SELECT t1.c1  FROM t1 WHERE t1.c1 IN (SELECT t2.c2 FROM t2)
```

Now if you mistakenly put t2.c1 in subquery you will get an error.

The other queries will also be more understendable:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 where t1.c1=t2.c2)

SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.total IN (SELECT t1.c1+t2.c2 FROM t2 WHERE t2.c2>t1.c1)
```

It is good to build this habit in writing the queries early because in more complex databases there are always fields with the same or similar names (primary keys are usually always "id" etc..) that could lead to serious errors.
It is not only problem of wrong deletes but I've seen important reports giving wrong figures for years.