# Why SQL subquery returns no error on trying to select not existing column?

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I use PostgreSQL 15 and have two tables:

- `table 1` has only one column `id1` (pkey) and has 6 rows (values 1-6)
- `table 2` has only one column `id2` (pkey) and has 6 rows with some another values

Then I try execute this SQL query (this is no real query, just for example):

`select id1 from table1 where id1 in (select id1 from table2)`

and get result: 6 rows from `table 1`.

I can not understand, why this query can even work if table 2 has no column with name `id1`

Query `select id1 from table2` returns an error as expected.

P.S.: If I try to execute this strange query from my C# application via npgsql v7 - I get an error.

Comment: Check [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/218871/subquery-gives-no-error-for-a-non-existing-column-with-the-same-name-as-in-the-o)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot!