# How to check if column exists in case statement?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I think a case statement would be the best approach to this but am open to any other suggestions. What I am trying to do is this. The query is generated based on a users input regarding the type report that they are seeking. The thing is all possible tables except for one contain a message_id column. On the odd table, I can get the data though another field which is time_sent. Here is an example of a generated query after user input.

```
  SELECT 
                ps.account_id,
                ba.account_name,
                NULL AS total_users,
                COUNT(DISTINCT(ps.uid)) AS unique_users,
                COUNT(DISTINCT r.msg_timestamp) AS messages_received,
                NULL AS total_clicks,
                NULL AS unique_clicks,
                COUNT(DISTINCT s.message_id) AS messages_sent, // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO USE A CASE OR SOME OTHER MEANS TO DETERMINE IF THE message_id COLUMN EXISTS
                COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ps.added BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-06-30' THEN ps.uid END) AS new_users
            FROM conversation_facebook_page_subscribers ps
                LEFT JOIN conversation_facebook_page_received r ON r.account_id = ps.account_id AND r.uid=ps.uid AND r.received_time BETWEEN '1577836800000' AND '1593561599999'
                LEFT JOIN conversation_facebook_page_sent s ON s.account_id = ps.account_id AND s.uid=ps.uid AND s.send_time BETWEEN '1577836800000' AND '1593561599999'
                LEFT JOIN business_assets ba ON ba.business_id = '3' AND ba.account_type = 'facebook_page' AND (ba.account_id = ps.account_id OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(ba.account_id, '_', -1) = ps.account_id)
            WHERE 
                (ps.account_id='104522080903905' OR ps.account_id='180004075382887' OR ps.account_id='85825440048')
                AND
                (r.account_id IS NOT NULL OR s.account_id IS NOT NULL)
            GROUP BY ps.account_id, ba.account_name
```

I have tried to use a case statement to check the name of the table and based on what the table name is select the appropriate field, but that didn't work. I have searched numerous questions on SO to see if I could find something that would work, but nothing I have found works.
Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You can't do that without dynamic SQL. All referenced identifiers are validated during query parsing, not during actual execution.

Comment: @trouble705 so when the column exists you want this `COUNT(DISTINCT s.message_id) AS messages_sent`.  What would you want if the column does not exist?  `COUNT(DISTINCT s.time_sent) AS messages_sent` ?

Comment: @mustaccio actually it is possible. Without dynamic SQL.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, yes, that is correct. If s.message_id does not exist, I would then need s.time_sent.

Comment: SO let me get this straight. Your query is not always exactly like above and in the `LEFT JOIN conversation_facebook_page_sent s` part you can replace the table with some other different table (and some of them have, some not, a `message_id` column). Correct?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, that is correct. It is an odd query, I know. But that is how I need to write it as sometimes it can be facebook, sometimes instagram, etc.

Comment: I see. My suggestion would be to have a set of queries, one for facebook, another for instagram, etc and select query accordingly. Otherwise, it's going to be a mess in the long run, as they, the various vendors keep changing their schemas and you add more vendors.

Comment: If you really want to go the messy way, check this answer to a similar question: **[Why can't I use a CASE statement to see if a column exists and not SELECT from it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66741/why-cant-i-use-a-case-statement-to-see-if-a-column-exists-and-not-select-from-i/66755#66755)**

Comment: and another to a similar problem for mysql: **[How to select specific rows if a column exists or all rows if a column doesn't](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44871/how-to-select-specific-rows-if-a-column-exists-or-all-rows-if-a-column-doesnt/44872#44872)**

Comment: SO we are back to @mustaccio's comment above. It may be possible without dynamic SQL but it would help your sanity to use dynamic SQL or predefined queries, one for each case.

Comment: I@ypercubeᵀᴹ, I agree with you... But, this is what I am tasked with doing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema-columns-table.html)

But you can't use it in a normal sql statement, because mysql will parse all parts.

I still have problems to understand, why you have missing columns in the first place.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure` (IN _account_id1,IN _account_id2)
BEGIN
        IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
                    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'conversation_facebook_page_sent ' 
                    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'message_id')) THEN
            SELECT 
                ps.account_id,
                ba.account_name,
                NULL AS total_users,
                COUNT(DISTINCT(ps.uid)) AS unique_users,
                COUNT(DISTINCT r.msg_timestamp) AS messages_received,
                NULL AS total_clicks,
                NULL AS unique_clicks,
           COUNT(DISTINCT s.message_id) AS messages_sent,
                COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ps.added BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-06-30' THEN ps.uid END) AS new_users
            FROM conversation_facebook_page_subscribers ps
                LEFT JOIN conversation_facebook_page_received r ON r.account_id = ps.account_id AND r.uid=ps.uid AND r.received_time BETWEEN '1577836800000' AND '1593561599999'
                LEFT JOIN conversation_facebook_page_sent s ON s.account_id = ps.account_id AND s.uid=ps.uid AND s.send_time BETWEEN '1577836800000' AND '1593561599999'
                LEFT JOIN business_assets ba ON ba.business_id = '3' AND ba.account_type = 'facebook_page' AND (ba.account_id = ps.account_id OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(ba.account_id, '_', -1) = ps.account_id)
            WHERE 
                (ps.account_id='104522080903905' OR ps.account_id='180004075382887' OR ps.account_id='85825440048')
                AND
                (r.account_id IS NOT NULL OR s.account_id IS NOT NULL)
            GROUP BY ps.account_id, ba.account_name;
        ELSE
            SELECT 
                ps.account_id,
                ba.account_name,
                NULL AS total_users,
                COUNT(DISTINCT(ps.uid)) AS unique_users,
                COUNT(DISTINCT r.msg_timestamp) AS messages_received,
                NULL AS total_clicks,
                NULL AS unique_clicks,
            COUNT(DISTINCT s.send_time) AS messages_sent,
                COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ps.added BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-06-30' THEN ps.uid END) AS new_users
            FROM conversation_facebook_page_subscribers ps
                LEFT JOIN conversation_facebook_page_received r ON r.account_id = ps.account_id AND r.uid=ps.uid AND r.received_time BETWEEN '1577836800000' AND '1593561599999'
                LEFT JOIN conversation_facebook_page_sent s ON s.account_id = ps.account_id AND s.uid=ps.uid AND s.send_time BETWEEN '1577836800000' AND '1593561599999'
                LEFT JOIN business_assets ba ON ba.business_id = '3' AND ba.account_type = 'facebook_page' AND (ba.account_id = ps.account_id OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(ba.account_id, '_', -1) = ps.account_id)
            WHERE 
                (ps.account_id='104522080903905' OR ps.account_id='180004075382887' OR ps.account_id='85825440048')
                AND
                (r.account_id IS NOT NULL OR s.account_id IS NOT NULL)
            GROUP BY ps.account_id, ba.account_name;
        END IF;
        
END
```

Comment: The first part of that does indeed work. But then when I add the else so that, if the message_id column doesn't exist, the query should then return the send_time, it says I have an error in my sql syntax. Maybe because all I am doing is " ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT s.send_time) AS messages_sent," ?

Comment: there is no else in sql see changed answer

Comment: That does look like it is working. Thank you very much. Accepting your answer now.

Comment: Actuall @nbk, that doesn't work. When I run the query with the email option, which is where the issue of not having the message_id field and instead needing the send_time, I get an error that message_id is an unknown column.

Comment: No mysql will also parse the true part, i think you need actually make a stored procedure